# Can I resize my image according to browser's zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website and I notice that when I zoom out on my browser, everything resizes except for the image. The image stays the same size no matter the browser's 100% or 50%. Is there a way I can code the image to resize according to the browser's zoom?

I am using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript for this website. And the image is rendered using JavaScript.

```js
function get_attrs() {
  // change the avatar based on requirements
  if (convStyle == 'dominant') {
    $("#robo-image").attr("src", "images/avatar/D-Robo.png");
    $(".user-description").prepend("<h3>Max</h3>");
  } else if (convStyle == 'submissive') {
    $("#robo-image").attr("src", "images/avatar/S-Robo.png");
    $(".user-description").prepend("<h3>Linus</h3>");
  }
}
```

```css
.robot-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3rem 0 3rem 2rem;
  /*padding: 3rem 0rem;*/
}

.robot-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3rem 0 3rem 2rem;
  /*padding: 3rem 0rem;*/
}

.robot-content-bottom {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*bottom: 5%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 robot-section">
  <div class="robot-content-top">
    <div id="messageContainer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="robot-content-bottom text-center">
    <img id="robo-image" alt="avatar" class="avatar-img">

    <div class="user-description">
      <h4>Your personal financial advisor</h4>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="user-description">-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<h3 style="margin-top: 30px;">Ethan</h3>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<h5>Your personal financial advisor</h5>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--</div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By default images will zoom with the rest of the page.  There's something stopping them doing that so you need to figure out what that is and change it.

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Can you supply a URL of your website?

Comment: @str I am using Google Chrome

Comment: You'll need to supply a **[mcve]** since what you describe does not happen by default.  We can't help you unless we can see the problem.

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm sorry but I am working on my local host right now. This is a screenshot of my page https://ibb.co/nB902J

Comment: @B.verly If we cannot reproduce your problem then we cannot help you.  You must supply code to demonstrate your problem or this question is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Archer I have added my codes. Thank you!

Comment: @B.verly you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your localhost.

Comment: @MoshFeu It's not relevant for them to supply a link to anything, regardless.  Once that link is dead then this question would be worthless.  We need code that demonstrates the problem and we don't have that.

Comment: @B.verly Try zooming in and out with this page and let us know what happens... https://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/c1psnkt8/

Comment: @Archer it will be good enough to help him for now..

Comment: @MoshFeu That's not what Stack Overflow is for.  Stop point hunting.

Comment: Thank you both so much for helping me out! I have gotten the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are dealing with the problem of width or height specified with percentage.

If you specify the width as a percentage (100%), the image will always be 100% width of the browser and will not shrink/grow with scaling.

The image with fixed width and height will shrink/grow and the image with width specified with percentage will not.

```
<img id="image" src="" width="622" height="350">
<img id="image2" src="" width="100%">
```

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/356153/).